# Python replace ',' within quotes, but keep other commas, then remove the quotes in a string

Tags: python-3.x

I currently have an string output that looks like this:

```
Shares Mil,"1,457","1,388","1,341","1,287","1,214","1,155","1,103","1,010",983,959,949
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
Shares Mil,1457,1388,1341,1287,1214,1155,1103,1010,983,959,949
```

Basically I want to remove the commas in the numbers that are surrounded by quotes and then be able to separate the strings by the commas using `.split(',')` into a list.

I had an idea to find the commas within the quotes using regular expression to remove the commas and then removing the quotes with `.replace('"','')` but I'm not sure how to.

I could `.split()` by the commas and remove the quotes and then manually join the separated numbers but there has to be a more efficient way of doing this, so I thought I'd ask for help.

Thanks!

Comment: I added a solution below, that relies on `regex`, which you'll need due to the non-uniform nature of the data in your string. (some numbers without quotes, some inside quotes; commas within strings that you don't want, and commas outside strings that you *do* want.  That would be rather complex, or impossible, using just `split` and `replace` and conditional logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not an easy way to distinguish the commas you want to keep, vs the ones you want to discard, using the usual python string functions.

You'll need to use [regular expressions](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions), aka [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html), to remove *only the `,`'s that are within quoted numbers.

Here is an [online regex compiler](https://pythex.org/?regex=%2C(%3F%3D%5Cd%2B%22)&test_string=Shares%20Mil%2C%221%2C457%22%2C%221%2C388%22%2C%221%2C341%22%2C%221%2C287%22%2C%221%2C214%22%2C%221%2C155%22%2C%221%2C103%22%2C%221%2C010%22%2C983%2C959%2C949&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0), and [another](http://www.pyregex.com/?id=eyJyZWdleCI6IiwoPz1cXGQrXCIpIiwiZmxhZ3MiOjAsIm1hdGNoX3R5cGUiOiJmaW5kYWxsIiwidGVzdF9zdHJpbmciOiJTaGFyZXMgTWlsLFwiMSw0NTdcIixcIjEsMzg4XCIsXCIxLDM0MVwiLFwiMSwyODdcIixcIjEsMjE0XCIsXCIxLDE1NVwiLFwiMSwxMDNcIixcIjEsMDEwXCIsOTgzLDk1OSw5NDkifQ%3D%3D) to debug your regex expressions.

And here is python's [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace) function, which is used to perform a Search and Replace operation on regex `matches`.

To do this, you'll also need to `import re` at the top of your file.  You won't need to download or install anything in order to do this, as it's part of Python.

```
import re

input_str = 'Shares Mil,"1,457","1,388","1,341","1,287","1,214","1,155","1,103","1,010",983,959,949'
desired_output_str = 'Shares Mil,1457,1388,1341,1287,1214,1155,1103,1010,983,959,949'

# use regex to *only* remove commas that are part of a number within a string
# matches commas that are followed immediately by a one or more digits and then double-quote
regex_pattern = r',(?=\d+")'

# we want to replace *those* commas with empty string (aka delete them)
replacement = ''

comma_less_numbers_str = re.sub(regex_pattern, replacement, input_str)
print(comma_less_numbers_str, "\n")

# now it's easy: just remove the "
output_str = comma_less_numbers_str.replace('"', '')

print(output_str)
print(output_str == desired_output_str)
print(desired_output_str)
```

[repl.it for this solution](https://repl.it/ML0m/13)

Regex is Extremely powerful, and comes in handy more often than you might think.  It simplifies *many* tasks you'll encounter.
I highly recommend spending a day to familiarize yourself with it's off putting nomenclature.
It's actually quite easy, once you start looking at it.
I linked documentation above.
You can also download an app to your phone to quickly learn regex in bite size chunks in your spare time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think regex is necessary here.  If you split the string on a double-quote character, you get a list where the odd numbered elements were inside the quotes.

So you can just replace commas in the odd numbered parts, and join it all back together.

```
s = 'Shares Mil,"1,457","1,388","1,341","1,287","1,214","1,155","1,103","1,010",983,959,949'
''.join([(ss if i%2==0 else ss.replace(',', '' )) 
          for i, ss in enumerate(s.split('"'))])
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another, simpler approach than using regular expressions. Python has a CSV file parser that accounts for quoted fields. Here's an example of what could work for you, with file "foo.csv" containing the example string that you want to parse:

```py
import csv

with open("foo.csv", "r", newline="") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, quotechar='"') # quotechar is the "magic" here

    for row in reader:
        print(",".join(x.replace(",", "") for x in row))
```

Note the `quotechar` argument in `csv.reader`. That's what allows Python to recognize a double-quote character as something that quotes CSV fields.